# Using setFlash While Redirecting Page

Tags: php, yii

I am creating a form that downloads a csv file using the PHP Yii framework. I want it to display `Your file should be downloading.` and stay on the same page after clicking download. Currently, it will download content, but no message displays. If I select the refresh button in the browser, it displays the `setFlash` message. Any suggestions?

```
if (isset($_GET['export'])) {

    $getData = $_GET['export'] == 'option1' ? $dataProvider->getData() : $myData->getData();

    $fileName = "file.csv";

    // Looping through $getData so that I can write to file

    Yii::app()->user->setFlash("success", "Your file should be downloading.");
    $this -> redirect(Yii::app()-> baseUrl . '/file.csv');
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the flash message on the server then you redirect the client to the CSV file, which downloads.
So lets see the steps:

1. user loads a page (where the download button is visible)
2. user clicks the button, and the server

   2.1 saves a message in the session

   2.2 redirects the user to a CSV file, then terminates

Note, that the server does not render the website again, nor the current page is refreshed. The setFlash saves a message for the current and the next request, until a getFlash is called.
getFlash is only called, when you refresh the page.

If you want to show the message without refreshing the page, you have to use javascript for that and remove the setFlash call from the script.

```
<div id="download-alert" style="display:none;">Your file should be downloading.</div>
<a id="download-btn" href="...">Download</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('a#download-btn').click(function(){ $("#download-alert").show(); })
</script>
```